# Implemention of voice calling feature in Android Wear App

Tags: twilio, wear-os, voip, agora

We have a stand alone Android app for wear OS, and we intend to add voice call functionality. Agora and Twilio, to the best of my knowledge, offer SDK for the Android platform. Is these SDKs compatible with Android Wear OS? Are there any challenges to integration with Android Wear OS?

Comment: did you try it? I have successfully implemented a voice call with a different SIP-library, but i would like to switch to Twilio.